# How to change the 'verbatim' font in biblatex references?

Tags: biblatex, xetex, siunitx, mathspec, eulervm

Cross-post of http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=24483 but since I get no answer there I'm hoping someone over here can help.

**The Goal:**
I want to use a custom font (Calluna and Calluna Sans by Exljbris) as main font for my document using `fontspec`, with `eulervm` as math font. Also, Calluna provides both OldStyle and Lining figures, of which I prefer the former in my main text, and the latter in mathmode. Furthermore, I'm a big fan of `siunitx` to format numbers with units. Finally I also use `biblatex` for typesetting my references.

**The Problem:**
`eulervm` comes with a set of numerals that just don't look very nice together with Calluna, especially when formatting numbers inline in the text. Also, the default setting to `eulervm` is to not use the Euler digits but the default roman digits. Apparently, these are not set by `fontspec` because in 'plain' math mode the Computer Modern digits are used and that looks even worse. To make matters worse, with or without the `euler-digits` option to `eulervm`, `siunitx` *always* uses the Euler numerals in math mode, and depending on the `detect-all` option also in text mode.

To correct these problems I use the `mathspec` package to set the digits in math mode to Calluna as well, while leaving the normal text alone. This solution works fine throughout the whole main text, including verbatim environments.

But then, enter references. Most of my references contain either an URL or a DOI (Digital Object Identifier), and these are handled in a verbatim style by `biblatex`. But as soon as I use the `\setmathfont` command, the numerals (and only the numerals) inside the `biblatex`-verbatim fields are changed to Calluna as well. However, the verbatim font (Latin Modern Mono) and Calluna are quite different, and don't mix very well. And unfortunately, the `\setmonofont` command does change the letters but not the numerals.

**The Question**
What is the best way to get the numerals consistent throughout the document? I prefer the Calluna numerals both in text and math mode, but the default mono font in verbatim mode. If it is possible to set the numerals in math mode without `mathspec`, using only `fontspec`, then I would prefer that since `mathspec` limits me to using `XeTeX`, while I would like to use `LuaTeX`.

**The Code**
Note that for compatibility I changed all references to Calluna in the code to fonts available by default on most computers.

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Article{Hay2011,
  Title                    = {Can humans force a return to a `Cretaceous' climate?},
  Author                   = {William W. Hay},
  Journaltitle             = {Sedimentary Geology},
  Year                     = {2011},
  Doi                      = {10.1016/j.sedgeo.2010.04.015},
  ISSN                     = {0037-0738},
  Language                 = {english},
  Note                     = {Causes of oxic - anoxic changes in Cretaceous marine environments and their implications for Earth systems },
  Number                   = {1-2},
  Pages                    = {5--26},
  Volume                   = {235},

  Journal                  = {Sedimentary Geology },
  Keywords                 = {Cretaceous},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[
        euler-digits    
    ]{eulervm}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    detect-all,
    }

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{Arial}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Arabic=Regular,Uppercase=Plain,Lowercase=Plain,Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}]{Times New Roman}% According to the manual this sets the digits to the regular arabics, while leaving the latin and greek letters untouched, which is intented, I want eulervm for maths letters.
\setmonofont[Ligatures={NoRequired,NoCommon,NoContextual},Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}]{Courier New}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear-comp,
    doi=true,
    url=true,
    sorting=nyvt,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\addglobalbib{test.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{Verify sans font}
The following line shows the normal verb command is unaffected:

{\scshape DOI:}\ \verb|10.1016/j.sedgeo.2010.04.015|

This is a sentence to test the various fonts for digits with or without \verb|\sisetup{detect-all}| or \verb|\setmathfont|. 1234567890, \(1234567890\), \SI{1234567890}{\metre}, \(\SI{1234567890}{\metre}\),\\ \num{1234567890}, \(\num{1234567890}\).

\begin{verbatim}
This is a test of numerals in the verbatim environment: 1234567890
\end{verbatim}

\textcite{Hay2011} shows the problem with the DOI, I included this one because it has an ugly mixture of letters and digits, showing the problem to its full extent.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a workaround with `fontspec` only. The trick is to define a new math symbol font for the lining figures.

I wouldn't use `detect-all`: numbers in `\SI` or `\num` should always be typeset in math mode (hence with lining figures).

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Article{Hay2011,
  Title                    = {Can humans force a return to a `Cretaceous' climate?},
  Author                   = {William W. Hay},
  Journaltitle             = {Sedimentary Geology},
  Year                     = {2011},
  Doi                      = {10.1016/j.sedgeo.2010.04.015},
  ISSN                     = {0037-0738},
  Language                 = {english},
  Note                     = {Causes of oxic - anoxic changes in Cretaceous marine environments and their implications for Earth systems },
  Number                   = {1-2},
  Pages                    = {5--26},
  Volume                   = {235},

  Journal                  = {Sedimentary Geology },
  Keywords                 = {Cretaceous},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
%  detect-all,
  math-rm=\mathlining,
}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\newfontfamily{\liningmain}[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers=Lining]{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont[Ligatures={Common,TeX},Numbers={Lining,Proportional}]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont[Ligatures={NoRequired,NoCommon,NoContextual},Numbers={Lining,Monospaced}]{TeX Gyre Cursor}

% A trick for extracting the family information
% which works independently of the chosen font
\begingroup
  \def\getfamily#1#2#3#4#5{#4}
  \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand\liningdefault{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \getfamily\csname liningmain \endcsname}}\x

\DeclareSymbolFont{liningmath}{\encodingdefault}{\liningdefault}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathlining}{liningmath}
\Umathcode`0="7 \symliningmath `0
\Umathcode`1="7 \symliningmath `1
\Umathcode`2="7 \symliningmath `2
\Umathcode`3="7 \symliningmath `3
\Umathcode`4="7 \symliningmath `4
\Umathcode`5="7 \symliningmath `5
\Umathcode`6="7 \symliningmath `6
\Umathcode`7="7 \symliningmath `7
\Umathcode`8="7 \symliningmath `8
\Umathcode`9="7 \symliningmath `9

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear-comp,
    doi=true,
    url=true,
    sorting=nyvt,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\addglobalbib{test.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{Verify sans font}
The following line shows the normal verb command is unaffected:

DOI: \verb|10.1016/j.sedgeo.2010.04.015|

URL: \url{10.1016/j.sedgeo.2010.04.015}

This is a sentence to test the various fonts for digits with or without 
\verb|\sisetup{detect-all}| or \verb|\setmathfont|.\\
No math: 1234567890,\\
Math:  \(1234567890\),\\
\verb|\SI| in text: \SI{1234567890}{\metre},\\
\verb|\SI| in math: \(\SI{1234567890}{\metre}\),\\
\verb|\num| in text: \num{1234567890},\\
\verb|\num| in math: \(\num{1234567890}\).

A test of math: $X=12$.

\begin{verbatim}
This is a test of numerals in the verbatim environment: 1234567890
\end{verbatim}

\textcite{Hay2011} shows the problem with the DOI, I included this one because it has an ugly mixture of letters and digits, showing the problem to its full extent.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid your solution does not produce lining numbers with the Calluna font. When I copy your entire example it works fine, and produces the same document as you've shown, but when I change references to TeX Gyre Termes to Calluna both in normal math mode as well as in `siunitx` commands the numbers are changed to OldStyle. In my original document Lining numbers work just fine.

Comment: If you would like to try it with the Calluna font, the regular font is available for free on various websites, including [myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/exljbris/calluna/). I noticed that when I use the 'Latin Modern' font instead of TeX Gyre your solution also works fine, so I'm wondering if it has something to do with the fact that these fonts are included with texlive, while Calluna is installed manually.

Comment: @hugovdberg Sorry, but I'm not going to register just to download a free font.

Comment: This is a bit odd, I did try some other Open Type fonts outside the texmf tree, and they worked so I once more switched to Calluna and now it works fine. I even copied your solution once more and, to my knowledge, made the exact same changes as before, and it still works.

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the root of the problem, because it occurred to me again, the problem is your solution works fine using any font (including Calluna) and `xetex`, but not using Calluna and `luatex`, then it produces old style numerals in mathmode as well. Do you have an idea where this would come from and how to fix it?

Comment: @hugovdberg What about other fonts and `lualatex`?

Comment: Other fonts, such as TeX Gyre or Latin Modern, work fine with `lualatex`. I have fontforge installed, and one thing I noticed in the OTF is that characters 48-57 (the numerals from 0 to 9) in Calluna are actually old style numerals, while in Latin Modern and TeX Gyre these are lining numerals, could that be the source of this problem? But why then only with `lualatex` and not with `xelatex`?

Comment: Ok, I just delved into the Calluna font a little more, and there are four versions of each numeral, with the corresponding OpenType features: 
- `one`, U+0031, old style;
- `one.pnum`, U+e536, lining;
- `one.tnum`, U+e541, lining;
- `one.onum_tab`, U+e557, old style. 
Apparently `xelatex` correctly selects the `onum_tab` feature, while `lualatex` selects the default numerals. For the TeX Gyre and Latin Modern fonts this happens to be the correct character, but Calluna defaults to Old Style. How can I make `lualatex` select the `tnum` feature as well?