# How to make lualatex select the correct OpenType features in math mode?

Tags: luatex, fontspec

After fiddling around with [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163259/46598) to my previous question, I finally discovered that `lualatex` is not selecting the `tnum` OpenType features, that is it uses the default numerals instead of the monospaced lining, whereas `xelatex` does select the correct numerals.

## The Goal

To use the Calluna font, with OldStyle figures in the main text, and Lining figures in mathmode, using code that's preferably compilable using `lualatex`.

## The Problem

Calluna has OldStyle figures by default, so the named character `one` returns a LowerCase 1. The code supplied by egreg is supposed to select the character `one.tnum` in math mode (or `pnum` as it stands in his original answer, but that only influences horizontal spacing). His code works fine using `xelatex`, but `lualatex` produces the character `one` instead, which for most fonts is actually a lining, proportional, figure, so exactly what egreg expected, but for Calluna this is an oldstyle, proportional numeral. Since Calluna is not freely available I changed the code to use EB Garamond which produces the same result.

### Edit

<strike>The problem really is in the combination of `lualatex` and egreg's code, since the normal `\setmainfont` options are respected perfectly fine by `lualatex`, if I set these to Lining I get Lining figures in the main text, but still not in the math text.
See [my original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163241/46598) as well for the reasons to use this code instead of `mathspec` for example.</strike>

After filing an issue at the `luaotfload` GitHub, it appears the problem was that fontspec uses the `Renderer=Full`/`mode=node` option by default, while in math mode `mode=base`/`Renderer=Basic` should be used. However, now the font features are applied inconsistently, randomly changing between compilations.

## The Question

How can I change the code, such that `lualatex` **consistently** uses the Lining, Monospaced numerals (OpenType feature `tnum`) in math mode, while using `eulervm` for all other characters in mathmode?

## The Code

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ifluatex}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    Ligatures={Common,TeX},
    Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},
    ]{EBGaramond12-Regular.otf}
%  ]{Calluna}
\setsansfont[
    Ligatures={Common,TeX},
    Numbers={Lining,Proportional},
    ]{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont[
    Ligatures={NoRequired,NoCommon,NoContextual},
    Numbers={Lining,Monospaced},
    ]{TeX Gyre Cursor}

% LuaTeX uses the full renderer by default, this does not work in math mode, so negate manually
\ifluatex
    \newfontfamily{\liningmain}[
        Ligatures={Common,TeX},
        Numbers={Lining,Monospaced},
        Renderer=Basic,
        ]{EBGaramond12-Regular.otf}
%        ]{Calluna}
\else
    \newfontfamily{\liningmain}[
        Ligatures={Common,TeX},
        Numbers={Lining,Monospaced},
        ]{EBGaramond12-Regular.otf}
%        ]{Calluna}
\fi

% A trick for extracting the family information
% which works independently of the chosen font
\begingroup
  \def\getfamily#1#2#3#4#5{#4}
  \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand\liningdefault{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    \getfamily\csname liningmain \endcsname}}\x

\DeclareSymbolFont{liningmath}{\encodingdefault}{\liningdefault}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathlining}{liningmath}
\Umathcode`0="7 \symliningmath `0
\Umathcode`1="7 \symliningmath `1
\Umathcode`2="7 \symliningmath `2
\Umathcode`3="7 \symliningmath `3
\Umathcode`4="7 \symliningmath `4
\Umathcode`5="7 \symliningmath `5
\Umathcode`6="7 \symliningmath `6
\Umathcode`7="7 \symliningmath `7
\Umathcode`8="7 \symliningmath `8
\Umathcode`9="7 \symliningmath `9

\sisetup{
        math-rm = \mathlining,
}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section{testing}

\begin{tabular}{p{.15\textwidth}p{.85\textwidth}}
\hline
Mode & Result\\
\hline
Normal font & \fontname\font\\
Lining font & {\liningmain\fontname\font}\\
Text mode & 1234567890\\
Math mode & \(1234567890\)\\
\verb|\SI| text mode & \SI{1042358769}{\metre}\\
\verb|\SI| math mode & \(\SI{1234567890}{\metre}\)\\
\verb|\num| text mode & \num{1234567890}\\
\verb|\num| math mode & \(\num{1234567890}\)\\
verbatim & \verb|1234567890|\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in `luatex` (possibly in `luaotfload`); if I ask the font corresponding to `\liningmain` from your code, I get

```
"[EBGaramond12-Regular.otf]/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;+liga;mapping=tex-text;+lnum;+tnum;"
```

with XeLaTeX and

```
"[EBGaramond12-Regular.otf]:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+liga;+tlig;+trep;+lnum;+tnum;"
```

with LuaLaTeX. So I prepared the following file

```
\input ifxetex.sty

\ifxetex
  \font\test="[EBGaramond12-Regular.otf]/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;+liga;mapping=tex-text;+lnum;+tnum;"
\else
  \input luaotfload.sty
  \font\test="[EBGaramond12-Regular.otf]:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+liga;+tlig;+trep;+lnum;+tnum;"
\fi

\test

1234567890

\textfont0=\test
$1234567890$

\bye
```

Since digits in math mode use `\textfont0` by their default definition, I should get two sets of lining figure. This is what I get with `xetex`

[image: XeTeX result]

and the result with `luatex` follows

[image]

So it appears that attributes are ignored by LuaTeX when the font is used in math mode. Where the bug resides I don't know.

---

For getting the font name, just add at the end of your example

```
\liningmain\fontname\font
```

and compile with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. I removed the option `RawFeature=+tnum` that just adds `+tnum` once more and makes no difference.

Comment: I should then just file an issue on the github of `luaotfload`? And how did you get the font specification? I'm a little curious if there is any difference between the specification of `liningmain` and `\setmainfont` that might cause `lualatex` to ignore the attributes.

Comment: Issue filed at https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/204